# can we use django authentication as a micro service in different project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my project we are trying to create micro service type architecture using djnago/django-rest-framework.

We've some services like:

```
User management service
Asset Management Service
Tool management service
```

All three services running on different Ports with different database.
Now my question is, 
Can we use `user management service` in `Asset` and `tools` service for `Token authentication`?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad question and without knowing more of your specific architecture, what you have tried and what features you want/need, it will be hard to give anything more than a starting point.

That being said, you could look at setting up a [Central Authentication Service](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home). (CAS) There's multiple packages for Django that help you with this.

Try looking into [Django CAS NG](https://github.com/mingchen/django-cas-ng) and [Django MamaCAS](https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas). Django CAS NG seems to be the more actively developed of the two.

Remember that with microservices, one of the big advantages is that there's nothing forcing you to use the same technology across your entire stack. It may well make sense to have your auth components provided by something entirely different, for example rolling a [KeyCloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) server to handle SSO.